# Soap Service for multiple responses-synchronous and asynchronous

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, jms

I have a requirement wherein a group of servers(multiple organizations) interact among themselves with SOAP services. A standard Wsdl is provided.
The requirement specifically states:

1. To Use SOAP over HTTPS.
2. Each request is a fire and forget. For each request an immediate synchronous acknowledgement is sent by the server, the server processes that request and then sends further responses(more than 1) asynchronously.

I have read that for a single request, multiple responses are not supported by http. As soon as the first response is sent, the connection is closed.
So JMS can be used for requirement-2, however the soap transport protocol will change to

```
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/jms"/>
```

when the required specification wsdl has

`<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>`

So I infer using JMS causes inter-operatbility among servers. Am I right?

Is there a way to use SOAP over http for the given requirement? Does spawning a new thread for each asynchronous response work? What is the best way to approach the solution?

Comment: I recomend you to use ESB

Comment: Thank you Gnk! "ESB" is exactly what I was looking for.